# System of ODE $\rightarrow$ Affine State-Space $\rightarrow$ System of ODE in Cauchy form

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, nonlinear

Given simple system of ODE:

\begin{cases} \dot{x}=G \\ \dot{z}=-z+\dot{f} \\ \dot{g}=-g+z \cdot s+u \\ \ddot{h}+\dot{h}+h=z \cdot m \end{cases}

where:

$x,z,g,h$ - state-space variables

$f=-(x+s)^2$

$s=\alpha \sin(\omega t)$

$m=(\frac{16}{\alpha^2}(\sin(\omega t)-\frac{1}{2}))$

This is my code transforming this system of equations into an affine state-space:

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

s[t] = \[Alpha] Sin[\[Omega] t]; 
m[t] = 16/\[Alpha]^2 (Sin[\[Omega] t]^2 - 1/2);

f = -(x[t] + s[t])^2;

asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x'[t] == g[t], z'[t] == -z[t] + D[f, t],
     g'[t] == -g[t] + z[t] s[t] + u[t], 
    h''[t] + h'[t] + h[t] == z[t] m[t]}, {{x[t], 1}, {z[t], 0}, {g[t],
      0}, {h[t], 0}}, {u[t]}, {g[t], h[t]}, t] // Simplify
```

And there is my result:

[image]

**Question**: *how to transform affine state-space to system of ODE, i.e. inverse tranform?*

I will be glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with using state space models, but the following approach is deduced from the docs:

> `AffineStateSpaceModel[{a,b,...},x,u,y,t]` explicitly specifies the input variables `u`, output variables `y`, and independent variable `t`,

where the first argument `{a, b, c, d}` provides

> the state equations *x'(t)==a(x(t))+b(x(t)).u(t)* and output equation *y(t)==c(x(t))+d(x(t)).u(t)*.

```
ClearAll[stateEqs];
stateEqs[
 Verbatim[AffineStateSpaceModel][{a_, b_, c_, d_}, x0_, u0_, y_, t_]
 ] :=
  Module[{u, x},
   x = Replace[x0, {xx_, x1_} :> xx, 1];
   u = Replace[u0, {uu_, u1_} :> uu, 1];
   D[x, t] == a + b . u
   ];
```

With `asys` as in the OP and `ode` being the differential equations from the OP, we have the following:

```
newode = asys // stateEqs // Thread;
newode // ExpandAll // MapAt[Simplify, #, {All, 2}] & // Column
```

[image]

```
Reduce[ode, {x'[t], z'[t], g'[t], h''[t]}] /.
     Thread[{x, z, g, h} -> Array[Subscript[\[FormalX], #] &, 4]] //
    Apply[List] //
   ExpandAll // MapAt[Simplify, #, {All, 2}] & // Column
```

[image]

Except for the first-orderization by `AffineStateSpaceModel` and the condition added by `Reduce`, the systems are the same.  Since the state space models produces by the first-order system and the OP's system are identical, it's impossible to deduce from the state space model whether or not the 4th and 5th equations should be composed to produce a second order equation.

Comment: how to remove the dots under the variables, and leave only $x_1...x_4"

Comment: @dtn The dotted letters are "formal symbols" such as `\[FormalX]`.  So `expr /. \[FormalX] -> x` will replace all occurrences of `\[FormalX]` with `x`. And `newode /. Thread[Array[Subscript[\[FormalX], #] &, 5] -> {x, z, g, h, h'}] // DeleteCases[True]` gives a system in the original terms (with `x'[t]` eliminated from equation (2)).

Comment: Thank you very much )

Comment: I have one more small question. How can you use this code to turn the transfer function into a dissent equation in the Cauchy form?

Comment: @dtn I’m afraid I don’t know what a dissent equation is.  And it doesn’t show up on Google for me.  Does it have another name or an short definition?